# Installing ruby on smartos plus

Tags: ruby, unix, solaris, joyent

So ive got a smartos 64 plus machine (joyent)

It DIDN'T have rails installed as i got a

```
Could not find gem 'rdoc (~> 3.4)', required by 'rails (= 3.0.9)', in any of the sources
```

Error trying to run a rails app (via rails s)

So I installed rails via

```
sudo gem install rails
```

And i got an error:

```
make: gcc: Command not found
```

It also said (when i tried to download the source and compile manually)

```
checking build system type... i386-pc-solaris2.11
checking host system type... i386-pc-solaris2.11
checking target system type... i386-pc-solaris2.11
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/apps/ruby-1.9.3-p125':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
```

Btw i also tried the smartos packager

```
pkgin in ruby19-rails-3.0.9
```

Im a bit confused because the SmartOS plus version is supposed to have most of this preinstalled!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you might have to do the gcc manually. [This post](http://mirrorshades.net/post/11283352457) has some information about it. `pkgin install gcc-compiler gcc-runtime gcc-tools-0` is the command they suggest.

Comment: just realized when i did gcc-v

Comment: The notes for smartos in their wiki mention gcc being in /usr/sfw/bin, so i checked there and didnt find it!

Comment: Interesting... I have not been into SmartOS yet but have been considering it so your question kind of niggled my brain a bit which was why I jumped in. At work the VMs I get are a Linux flavor that are supposed to have gcc by default but for some reason it is not on the VM

Answer (score 3):

To allow Ruby Gems to build native binary packages you will need to install GCC and Make. It seems like GCC is not on the machine by default.

```
pkgin install gcc47 gmake

gem install <your gem>
```